# SSIS - Execute Task with more than 1 success Precedence Constraint (Arrow)

Tags: ssis

I have a task which can go one way or the other depending on a variable value from the Script task. (Done by an expression)

[image]

At the end of either of the branches I would like to kick off a task but I cannot, I believe it's due to having 2 data flows attached to it.

[image: ing]

Therefore I need to duplicate the task on each branch.

[image]

Is there a way of not duplicating this and just use one task like the 2nd screenshot shows?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make screenshot 2 work you need to change precedence constraint logic to use OR.

[image]

It will make the precedence constraints dashed.

[image]

I have to admit I have only ever used screenshot #3 method in SSIS (but this is a very common practice in other languages like C#).